# Microsoft Access Search Box not Turning Up Results

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to create a search box that acts like the navigation search function at the bottom of the page in access. This is so the users of my data base have an easier time navigating the database.

My code currently is

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
Dim bkmk As Variant
Dim strField As String

Me.RecordsetClone.MoveFirst
'Find the first record that matches what
'is in the search text box.
Me.RecordsetClone.FindFirst "B3 Like " _
    & Chr(34) & Me.txtsearch & "*" & Chr(34) _
    & "OR Item Like" _
    & Chr(34) & Me.txtsearch & "*" & Chr(34) _


If Me.RecordsetClone.NoMatch Then
    MsgBox "No Match"
Else
    bkmk = Me.RecordsetClone.Bookmark
    Me.Recordset.Bookmark = bkmk
End If
End Sub
```

When I apply this code to my search function even when I'm testing with an item that is known to be in the database it is returning the "No Match" message box. My end goal is to have a search function that will search multiple fields in the back end table.

Comment: Not entirely sure but I think you need a space before `OR` and after the second `Like`.

Comment: @KostasK. I believe you are correct however when I made this change the search worked once and then has been returning the "No Match" message box every time after

Comment: I am writing from mobile app so not tested but you can try by removing Chr(34) function. Chr(34) is for double quote. So try, `Me.RecordsetClone.FindFirst "B3 Like '" & Me.txtsearch & "*' OR [Item] Like '"  & Me.txtsearch & "*'"`

Comment: LIKE operator works on string and string values need to pass with single quotes at starting and ending like  `LIKE 'My Search Text*'`

Comment: @Harun24HR thanks for the suggestion. I tried your revised code and I'm still returning the same "No Match" message even when searching for a known good entry.

Comment: What is `B3`, field name? I will give try on tomorrow. It must be very simple.

Comment: The B3 is a plain text field. Usually consisting of a mix of numbers and letters. The average length is usually less than 10 characters.

Comment: I tested code with space fixes and Chr(34). Works for me every time.

Comment: @June7 do you mean the following? `Me.RecordsetClone.FindFirst " B3 Like " _
    & Chr(34) & Me.txtsearch & "*" & Chr(34) _
    & " OR Item Like " _
    & Chr(34) & Me.txtsearch & "*" & Chr(34) _`

Comment: Yes, I do except no space in front of B3. Edit question to show sample of your data.